# Acelerar evento .error en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

quiero controlar que una imagen se cargue de forma correcta y si da error que se ponga otra imagen de reemplazo. Todo funciona de forma correcta, pero mientras se produce la demora de tiempo, esta imagen no sale, y me aparece el hueco vacío. ¿Como puedo acelerar esto? Las url de la imagen provienen de la consulta a una base de datos.

```
jQuery(".webcam>a>img").error(function() {
            jQuery(this).attr("src", "https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/Estaciones/public/images/errorWebCam.jpg").css({
                "min-height": "350px",
                "display":"block",
   

            }).one()
    });
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').each(function(){
    if($(this)[0].naturalHeight == 0){
         $(this).attr("src", "https://www.example.com/wp- 
            content/plugins/Estaciones/public/images/errorWebCam.jpg").css({
               "min-height": "350px",
               "display":"block",


        }).one();
    }
});
```

});